# Is there any tricks for fast-memory access?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, pointers

I am very new to the world of C++ programming, so sorry for my amatuerish question:

I get a large block of data stored in the main memory (1-D array), and I need to access some of the data there frequently, my way of doing this is:

```
float *x=new float[20];//array to store x;
int *indlistforx=new int[20];//array to store the index of x;
float *databank=new float[100000000];//a huge array to store data

/... fill data to databank.../


for (int i=0;i<N;i++)//where N is a very large number;
 {
  /... write index to indlistforx.../
  getdatafromdatabank(x, indlistforx, databank);
  //Based on the index provided by indlistforx, read data from databank then pass them to x

  /...do something with x.../
  };
```

Is there any efficient/fast way to access these data(the index for x are not aligned, and it is impossible to be aligned)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `new float[100000000];`? May you live in the 70's...

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Is some part of your code running too slowly?

Comment: I don't get the question. What is `x`?

Comment: I edited my codes...  What I want is: (1)read data from databank, then pass them to x; (2) then do something with x; do (1) and (2) repeatedly (in a for-loop). And the performance bottleneck for this function is the data-reading part, so I want to know is there anyway that can improve this part...

Comment: @H2CO3: the data I handle is huge, which occupies roughly 20+ GB memory in double format, thats why I use f32 instead of double...

Comment: The fastest memory reads occur when you 1) have your data in cache and 2) you read the largest native width at a time

Comment: for 2 you can do a `reinterpret_cast<>` on the part you want to read and attempt to read in larger chunks? I'm no expert tho

Comment: Thanks, I will try, btw, can anyone tell me if multi-threading helps in this case (fast memory access)? in theory my work can be done in parrallel.

Comment: @user1748356: H2C03 wasn't speaking in regards to `float` v `double`, he was speaking in regards to using manual memory management instead of using better, RAII style alternatives. (at least, I assume this is the case)

Comment: Does RAll style memory-management offer any advantage in terms of performance?  I am all for sheer performance, many thanks

Comment: RAII generally offers advantages in terms of correctness and simplicity, but there shouldn't be any _disadvantage_ in terms of performance

Comment: @user1748356:  You don't always have to sacrifice safety for performance, and that is the case here.  Honestly, if you're writing `new` and `delete` a lot in your C++ code, in the vast (*vast*) majority of cases, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536091/how-to-cache-objects-created-from-mysql-database I implemented a system where I load a certain amount of data when requested and store it in memory. If it is requested again I just have to access my cached data. If the requested data is not cached load it from the db and save it in my cache system (delete old data which hasn't been accessed for a while). The amount of data you can cache depends on the form of data and obviously your memory.

Comment: @Layne, thanks, the system you developed is surely wonderful.

Comment: @Ed S.:thanks for your suggestions, I get the wrong impression: in order to squeeze the last drop of performance,  class/struct should be avoided as much as possible, I may try this RAII idea after I fix the performance issue of my program, but thanks anyway, it certainly looks like it can help fixing memory-leaking.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't really shown how you're accessing your databank, so this is all very speculative:

- is `indlistforx` a list of 20 indices into the databank, so you're doing 20 random accesses?

  - what is the stride in these indices: are they consecutive, or close together, or random?
  - if they're consecutive or close together, sorting them may help (so you're reading in ascending order to improve prefetch, and grouping reads from the same cache line together)
- how much do different groups of 20 indices jump around? can they overlap?

  - if they can't overlap, so your databank is effectively partitioned into some chunk size, then handling each partition on a different processor might increase the amount of effective cache you can use (if you have multiple processors)
  - if requests can overlap running them concurrently can still work if the databank is read-only.  If anything writes to the databank, this becomes a recipe for cache thrashing
- can you reorder your accesses at a higher level to get better cache behaviour: more sequential, better spatial or temporal locality of reference?

  - this is essentially the same as my first suggestion, but above the level of a single `indlistforx` request
  - similarly, consider reordering them to effectively partition the databank and try the multi-processor idea

---

Without seeing all the code (or a representative sample, and I understand even that may be too large) it's hard to go into any more detail.

However, there is one general technique that might work ... it might also be so heavyweight that the implementation cost outweighs the savings.

- make your `getfromdatabank` return a future/promise/whatever, rather than completing synchronously (or a vector of 20 futures, if that's not too fine-grained)
- try to dispatch lots of these asynchronous requests in parallel, either in separate threads (where accessing the futures would be a blocking operation) or using an event loop to handle completions with something like explicit co-routines
- have a dedicated thread aggregate all the databank accesses from multiple requests, and reorder them for better cache performance

This can only work if the extra synchronization overhead is dominated by improved read performance, and if you can usefully run many queries in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, in my case, it is random-access of data, but without over-lap.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, yes, the reason why I cannot post the codes is because I use simd intrinsic functions and CUDA codes extensively so the codes are too long and most part of them are irrelevant to random memory-accessing.

Answer (score 2):

Since a float needs to be initialized, you really should use a std::vector<>, it is not slower, construct and fill like this:

```
std::vector< float > databank( 100000000, 0.0f );
```

There are a few options for speedup:

1) If there is a reasonably large key(index) reuse, then you can use a caching or memorization strategy of some sort.
See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html for an example.

2) You can split the processing into multiple threads, using say std::async().

3) Make sure your compiler has simd instructions (sse on x86) turned on and is using them. If not force the use of simd by using compiler intrinsics. This will allow a near 4x improvement.

Comment: Many thanks, I will try your suggestions, as for SIMD, yes, my program is compiled with AVX option.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but this answer is essentially incorrect. Switching to vectors is not going to help. The only difference between `std::vector<float>` and a `float*` is safety. Speed? No. Vectors are just an RAII-safe wrapper around a raw pointer. The chief culprit is the random access; switching to a vector won't change that. What will change that is to get rid of that random access.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't how you are representing your `databank`. The problem is how you are using it. Randomly accessing widely separated pieces of your `databank` in short order is going to kill your performance. Your `getdatafromdatabank(x, indlistforx, databank)` with that `indlistforx` almost guarantees poor performance. The random access enabled by that `indlistforx` comes with a significant performance penalty. If that random access absolutely necessary because how the algorithms that use your `databank` work, that's just a price you will have to pay.

You'll get much better performance if you can modify your algorithms so that they access contiguous chunks of memory in your `databank`. Change `getdatafromdatabank` so that you specify the first index only (the index of the element that you want loaded into `x[0]`) rather than an array 20 indices.

Is there a reason that `x` is sized at 20? You'll get best performance if you just barely manage to keep the output `x` array and the relevant chunk of the `databank` in level 1 cache. Performance will start to decrease, and may decrease significantly, if the size of `x` increases beyond this optimal size.

Comment: I have to use random access, I can re-arrange the databank to allow chunk-based access, however that will reduce the performance of other part of the codes, and the trade-off isnt pretty(actually the exact reason why I have to let it access the databank randomly is to enable the other part of my codes access the data "chunkly"), thats why I have to stick to random-access of the large chunk of data, I just want to know if there are any ways to improve the performance of random-access, I wonder if multi-threading will help much?